# Proof for the general formula for $a^n+b^n$.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Based on the following observations. That is

> $$a+b = (a+b)^1  \\  a^2+b^2 = (a+b)^2-2ab \\ a^3+b^3 = (a+b)^3-3ab(a+b) \\ a^4+b^4= (a+b)^4-4ab(a+b)^2+2(ab)^2\\ a^5+b^5 
> = (a+b)^5 -5ab(a+b)^3+5(ab)^2(a+b)\\\vdots$$

I came to  make the following conjecture as  general formula.

> $$ a^n +b^n =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k \frac{n\Gamma(n-k)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-2k+1)}(a+b)^{n-2k}(ab)^k $$ where $\Gamma(.) $ is gamma function.

I tried up proving the result using binomial theorem $\displaystyle (a+b)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n a^{n-r}b^r$ for positive integers  $a,b$ however, I didn't find  any elegance in the work.  So in the expect of some beautiful proofs,  I wish to share  general formula here.

Thank you

Comment: You can use Newton's formula ( recursive formula), I guess.

Comment: @user675453, I don't get you much.  Can I have the reference or source for the recursive formula, please? :)

Comment: I'm not able to find any source (easily).maybe it's called something else. It says, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then, for $S_n= \alpha^n +\beta^n$,  $aS_{n+2}+bS_{n+1}+cS_n=0$

Comment: I think you talking about Newton - Girad identities.

Comment: It's not a conjecture, it's a known result, if you compare it with formula (15) for Chebyshev polynomials, here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html The connection is not obvious, admittedly.

Comment: @Professor Vector,  I wasnot known  with the fact since I came up to this result by making simple observations :).  It needs to edited in the body problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ are roots of $x^2=(a+b)x-ab$. Therefore, $a^{n+2}=(a+b)a^{n+1}-(ab)a^n$ and analogously for $b$.

Let $p_n=a^n+b^n$. Then $p_{n+2}=(a+b)p_{n+1}-(ab)p_n$ is a simple recurrence. The initial values are of course $p_0=2$ and $p_1=a+b$.

This recurrence is a special case of [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Answer (score 5):

Let $|\mathbb{A}|=a$ be an alphabet on $a$ letters and let $|\mathbb{B}|=b$ be an alphabet in $b$ letters. Notice that the left hand side $a^n+b^n$ is the number of strings of length $n$ with either all letters in $\mathbb{A}$ or all letters in $\mathbb{B}.$ Let $\mathcal{C}=\{x\in (\mathbb{A}\cup \mathbb{B})^n:\text{x contains letters from both alphabets}\}$ then $a^n+b^n=(a+b)^n-|\mathcal{C}|.$ Now consider $$\mathcal{C}=\bigcup _{i=1}^{n-1}A_i,$$ where $A_i=\{x\in (\mathbb{A}\cup \mathbb{B})^n:x_i \text{ and }x_{i+1}\text{ are not in the same alphabet}\}$ then using **inclusion-exclusion** you get that $$|\mathcal{C}|=\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{i-1}\sum _{X\in \binom{[n-1]}{i}}|\bigcap _{x\in X}A_x|.$$
Notice that $|A_i|=(a+b)^{n-2}(ab)^1$ and in general $|\bigcap _{x\in X} A_x|=(a+b)^{n-2|X|}(ab)^X$ because you are free to choose the alphabet in $n-2k$ positions and you have to alternate in $2k$ positions($a^k$ for half and $b^k$ for half) and so plugging in the equation and noticing that you do not want to repeat index(so taking consecutive indices) because you would be overcounting (so instead of the usual $\binom{n-1}{i},$ you get $\binom{n-i-1}{i-1}+\binom{n-i}{i}=\frac{n}{n-i}\binom{n-i}{i}$ depending on if you want the last letter to be alternative or no) we get that
$$a^n+b^n=(a+b)^n-\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{i-1}\frac{n}{n-i}\binom{n-i}{i}(a+b)^{n-2i}(ab)^i=\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\frac{n}{n-i}\binom{n-i}{i}(a+b)^{n-2i}(ab)^i.$$
This fits in the Combinatorial interpretation of the Chebyshev polynomials (commented above by **Professor Vector**). See, for example, **Counting on Chebyshev Polynomials,** A. Benjamin and D. Walton

Answer (score 3):

You want to express $x^n+b^n$ in terms of their sum, or (for convenience) half-sum $s:=\dfrac{a+b}2$, and geometric mean $p:=\sqrt{ab}$.

We have

$$2as=a^2+ab=a^2+p^2,$$ giving

$$a=s\pm\sqrt{s^2-p^2},b=s\mp\sqrt{s^2-p^2}.$$

Now

$$a^n+b^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\left(s^{n-k}(s^2-p^2)^{k/2}+(-1)^ks^{n-k}(s^2-p^2)^{k/2}\right)
\\=2\sum_{j=0}^{2j\le n}\binom n{2j}s^{n-2j}(s^2-p^2)^j.$$

This further expands as

$$2\sum_{j=0}^{2j\le n}\binom n{2j}s^{n-2j}(s^2-p^2)^j
=2\sum_{j=0}^{2j\le n}\binom n{2j}s^{n-2j}\sum_{i=0}^j\binom ji(-1)^is^{2(j-i)}p^{2i}
\\=2s^n\sum_{j=0}^{2j\le n}\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^i\binom n{2j}\binom ji\left(\frac ps\right)^{2i}.$$

Some more work is needed to regroup the terms by equal $i$.